# Append to text file repeatedly

Tags: python

I'm writing to the same text file multiple times during a python program. How to write new contents at the end of text file?  That is I need always to place the pointer to the end of lines of the "out" file and write the new text.

I have tried the following, which didn't work?

```
out.seek(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, it depends...

- If you don't close the file and don't move the file pointer (using `seek`) between two write operations, new content is appended automaticcaly at the end:

  ```
  file.write("Hello")
  file.write("World")
  ```
- If you have closed your file, you could re-open it in `"a"` (for append) mode

  ```
  file.write("Hello")
  file.close()

  file = open("myfile.txt", "a")
  file.write("World")
  ```

  or (if you use [context managers](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)):

  ```
  with open("myfile.txt", "w") as file
      file.write("Hello")

  # implicit close here

  with open("myfile.txt", "a") as file
      file.write("World")
  ```
- If you have moved the file pointer using [`seek`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) , you could position at the end using `seek(0,2)` (this mean "zero bytes from the end")

  ```
  file.write("Hello")
  file.seek(here-or-there)
  file.do_this_or_that

  file.seek(0, 2)
  file.write("World")
  ```

Comment: You should use `with open(...) as file:` instead. +1 anyway (for very detailed answer)

Comment: @AnotherTest Yeah. You are right. I used very basic examples just to make the point. But using context manager if far better than "plain" open and close hanging around.

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux : I use both to_csv and out.write methods? It seems file is over written?

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage The answer you have here are pretty generic. As the question seems more complicated than we thought at first (are you using panda?) you should post a _new_ more detailed question showing some sample of your code. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106249/update-a-question-or-post-a-new-question

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux : Yes, I'm using pandas, I'll start a new question with more details, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in `append` mode:

```
open(filename, 'a')
```

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) :

> 'a' opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is
>   automatically added to the end.

Comment: Ok,Thanks very much! That is what I wanted! :)